# Plain custom CSS in Laravel seems not to work

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I don't know why CSS file is not working on my Laravel project but I'm pretty sure i put those correctly into folders and whenever I try to look at the source code it shows my CSS codes but it didn't change anything.

My css file located here

```
public->css->style.css
```

along with my bootstrap.min.js my bootstrap are working fine anyway.

and in my Blade file:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I saw Laravel documentation and saw the Laravel Mix. Do you think that may be the cause? Is it required to use that Laravel Mix and not allowing users to use their own compiled CSS?

Comment: Can you see “style.css” in your browser’s developer tools?

Comment: Try `URL::asset()`

Comment: hi yes i saw it in my developer tools but it changes nothing. i also tried that URL::asset() still don't work

Comment: Does the style.css file in your developer tools have CSS in it? I think the style.css file is getting passed to your browser. It’s just that the styles aren’t being applied because there’s something wrong with the CSS in style.css.